# I have to press CTRL+D twice to end the input, why?how to correct?

Tags: c

I am supposed to write a program specified here:

```
Input

The input will consist of a series of pairs of integers a and b,separated by a space, one pair of integers per line. you should read the input until EOF.
Output

For each pair of input integers a and b you should output the sum of a and b in one line,and with one line of output for each line in input.
Sample Input

1 5
7 2

Sample Output

6
9
```

an I write this:

```
     #include
```

```
 main() {
 int a, b;
 int sum[100];
 int i,j;
 char c;

 for(i=0; i<100; i++) sum[i]=0;

 i=0;
 do {
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
sum[i]=a+b;
    i++;
  } while((c=getchar())!=EOF);

 for(j=0; j<i-1; j++) printf("%d\n", sum[j]);
 }
```

what is strange for me is: why should I press CTRL+D(EOF) twice to end the input?Is there any better way to write this code?

Comment: One EOF is for `scanf` function, one is for `getchar`. You need to reorganize your program, so it does not wait twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first CTRL-D breaks the scanf. After that your program waits in getchar. If you check the output from scanf you have only one check.

```
#include <stdio.h>


main() {
    int a, b;
    int sum[100];
    int i,j;
    char c;

    for(i=0; i<100; i++) sum[i]=0;

    i=0;
    while ( 2==scanf("%d %d", &a, &b))
    {   
        sum[i]=a+b;
        i++;
    }   

    for(j=0; j<i-1; j++) printf("%d\n", sum[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shouldn't rely on `EOF` being hit by `getchar()`. Change this:

```
do {
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    ...
} while((c=getchar())!=EOF);
```

to:

```
do {
    if (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) != 2)
        break;
    ...
} while((c = getchar()) != EOF);
```

Alternatively you might omit `getchar()` call completely:

```
while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) == 2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `scanf()` reads your line of input, it reads the two numbers, but it leaves the newline that terminates the line in the input stream. Then when `getchar()` reads the next character, it reads that newline. Since the newline is not EOF, it returns to the beginning of the loop.

Now `scanf()` runs again, and it sees the EOF that you typed after the newline. It returns without updating the variables. Then `getchar()` is called again, and you have to type another EOF for it to get it.